# Using iTextSharp to copy TableLayoutPanels to pdf

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, itext, tablelayoutpanel

Good Afternoon everyone.  I have a question involving taking data in a tablelayoutpanel and placing it into a .pdf using iTextSharp (Unless someone knows a better technology).  The tableLayout panel consists of 1 column with 1 row by default and has rows dynamically added given what the data returns.

Here is what I have for printing:

```
    private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            dialog.Title = "Save file as...";
            dialog.Filter = "Pdf File |*.pdf";

            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(dialog.FileName, FileMode.Create));

                doc.Open();
                Paragraph entry1 = new Paragraph("Hello World!");

                //Page 1 Printing
                PdfPTable LegendsForTable = new PdfPTable(this.tblPnlLayLFT.ColumnCount);

                doc.Add(entry1);
                doc.Close();

                MessageBox.Show("File saved");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(@"ERROR: Issue encountered while trying to print. " + Environment.NewLine
                            + @"Contact ITSupport with the following the following error" + Environment.NewLine
                            + exception);
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know a method to copy `tablelayoutpanel` to .pdf?

Comment: *"I have a question"* - which question is that exactly?

Comment: My apologies thought it was clear.  The question would be Does anyone a method to copy tablelayoutpanel to .pdf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out myself.

Step 1 was to create a loop that iterates through the table layout panels and place the order that I want into a list.

int reIterator = 1;
            int replicateIterator = 1;

```
        List<string> table1List = new List<string>();

        for (int counter = 0; counter < 6; counter++)
        {
            while (reIterator < 7)
            {
                string currentLabel = "LblRE" + reIterator + "R" + replicateIterator;

                Label reLabel = this.Controls.Find(currentLabel, true).FirstOrDefault() as Label;

                if (reLabel.Text != null)
                {
                    table1List.Add(reLabel.Text);
                    reIterator = reIterator + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    table1List.Add(reLabel.Text = "");
                    reIterator = reIterator + 1;
                }
            }
            //Builds next row
            if (reIterator == 7)
            {
                replicateIterator = replicateIterator + 1;
                reIterator = 1;
            }
        }
```

Then using iTextSharp I am able to loop through using the list and add the data to a PDF.